# Using future simple instead of future perfect

Tags: future-perfect, future-constructions

Is it correct to say:

> I will finish my work before you come back.

Or should I use future perfect:

> I will have finished my work by the time you come back.

and are the two sentences same in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Both constructions are valid but they look at the completion of your work from different time perspectives.

The first example looks forward to the completion of your work.

In the second example, you are writing from the perspective of someone who has completed the task. You are looking back on a future event.

We often use this latter construction when we are impatient for the arrival of a future event, especially when we are going through a tough period in the meanwhile.

**This time next week, I will have finished my studies.**

**In just a few months' time I will have qualified as a doctor.**

**Just two more days and I will have been discharged from hospital.**

**Another week and I will have completed my military service.**

Comment: what do you mean by (**you are writing from the perspective of someone who has completed the task**), I didn't finish my work yet, it will happen in the future.

Comment: You are imagining that you have completed it, even though it is not yet finished.